# App to alert me of firmware updates on a rooted Android phone

Tags: android

Are there any apps that will notify me of firmware updates available on a rooted phone?

The built in firmware check on my Samsung Galaxy SIII will no longer work on the stock ROM, because it has detected that the phone is rooted.

Are there any that will download the updated ROM for me too?

Answer (score 1):

[ROM Manager (Premium)](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.koushikdutta.rommanager.license) (not the [free version](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.koushikdutta.rommanager)) lists this amongst its features:

> **Premium Version:**
>
> - Incremental update zips (save your data plan!)
> - Premium ROMs
> - **Receive notifications for when your ROM is updated!**
> - Automatic backups
> - Install Queue
> - Web Connect
> - Backup Download Server lets you easily transfer backups as flashable zips to your computer.

(emphasis mine). I have not tested it myself, but I assume this does *not* apply to "OTA updates" for your (rooted) stock-ROM – but only for ROMs installed with *ROM Manager* itself (i.e. where *ROM Manager* knows the sources of "where to look for").

Second, there's also [ROM Installer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.jrummy.apps.rom.installer):

> **Features**
>
> - Many ROMs and ZIPs to download for hundreds of devices
> - One click install of the latest TWRP, ClockworkMod and ClockworkMod Touch Recovery
> - Backup and restore your current ROM (nandroid)
> - Extract apps and data and manage current nandroid backups
> - Install ZIPs with the easy to use ROM Installer. Install many ZIPs at one time.
> - **Get notifications and OTA updates for ROMs and recoveries**
> - Navigate ROMs and files on the popular ROM hosting website, goo.im

Again, I didn't verify for what ROMs the notifications are valid here. It's very likely the same rules apply here.

Comment: You're correct, Rom Manager does *not* alert for updates for the stock ROM. Therefore, I think that this might not suit OP's needs, since he mentioned the stock ROM in his post. (Can't say for sure about ROM Installer)

Comment: @dotVezz I agree. Wanted to give him that option, though – let's leave the decision to him. After all, it might help others as well. // Nice to see you here, dotVezz! Once more, we can "team up" :)